# D3js v5.16.0 is not loading in IE>11, where it has fetch used in d3.min.js/d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, d3.js, fetch

[Attached the screenshot that shows fetch is not supported in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls5Yx.png)

I am not using any framework or any other platform like nodejs. It is pure Javascript and d3js code. I  tried adding polyfills from the cdn

Is there any otherway to fix this ?

Added the fetch.js from package downloaded from github. though the issue persists

```
<script src="js/fetch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: The fix is to use the [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch). If it isn't working for you then we need to see your code where you've added and used it

Comment: how to add polyfill as a script tag?

Comment: `<script src="path-to/fetch-polfill.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest try to make a test with the code below. It is working with the IE 11 browser without any error. It may help you to fix your issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="zh-Hant-TW">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>d3 v5 in IE 11</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h2>subreddit</h2>

    <div id="d"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.1/es6-promise.min.js" integrity="sha256-45YA33UQCDcJsntBst2bhka2t/LBNHP7RNvpllHPkQ0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.1/es6-promise.auto.min.js" integrity="sha256-OI3N9zCKabDov2rZFzl8lJUXCcP7EmsGcGoP6DMXQCo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.4/fetch.min.js" integrity="sha256-eOUokb/RjDw7kS+vDwbatNrLN8BIvvEhlLM5yogcDIo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      d3.json('https://www.reddit.com/api/trending_subreddits.json').then(function(data) {

        d3.select('#d').selectAll('p').data(data.subreddit_names).enter().append('p').text(function(d){ return d });

      });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Reference:

[Use D3 version 5 in IE 11](https://solnone.github.io/javascript/2018/05/11/d3js-v5-IE11)

If the issue persists then we need the sample code to check for the issue. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: But it got another issue where append doesn't work in IE 
Code:
 d3.xml(_this.config.imagePath+s.type+".svg") 
.then(function(data){ 
const slotsvg = data.documentElement; 
d3.select(slotsvg).attr('x', svgx); 
d3.select(slotsvg).attr("y", svgy);
 d3.select(slotsvg).attr("width", svgW);
 d3.select(slotsvg).attr("height", svgH); d3.select(slotsvg).attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none"); slot.node().append(slotsvg); })

Comment: Its looks like a different issue. We need a detailed sample with the proper information to check that issue. I suggest try to create a new thread for it. Thanks for your understanding.